# What is the difference between eine and ein?

Tags: gender, standard-german

I am learning German using the `Duolingo` app in my mobile.

In one of the exercises I type "eine Mädchen ein Frau" as an answer for an audio but I got this error:

> **Careful "Mädchen" actually takes a neutral article, like most nouns that end in "chen"**

I changed the order to "ein Mädchen eine Frau" to correct it but I still don't understand why the first one is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite easy: For feminin (defined article: die) substantives, you use "eine", for masculin (defined article: der) and neutral (defined article: das), you use "ein" as undefined article.

> Das Mädchen -> Ein Mädchen
>   Die Frau -> eine Frau